# Keybindings based on delay in vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I would want vim to leave insert mode if the last key pressed is a } and no other key has been pressed for a while. Is this possible?

Comment: hmmm, the variable that controls the timeout for mappings is `help: timeoutlen, default is 1000ms`. Need to read some more...

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `:timer` command is still on the [Vim TODO list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/todo.html#todo.txt).

If you want to vote for Vim features, you have to become a registered Vim user or sponsor. [See the sponsor page](http://www.vim.org/sponsor/index.php).

Comment: Interesting, will not mark this as accepted since I hope there is some way of getting around that :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's worth it, but I think you should be able to do a workaround with info linked below.  Notice that the particular keycodes in main tip need to be changed in latest versions of Vim:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically

http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/8c535e5cf2b35f63/e40998ff7f2d909b?lnk=gst&q=yakov&pli=1